# Probability of sum of uniforms comparison

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $0 \le x \le y \le 1$, I would like to find a closed formula for
$$ X\sim U(x,1),U\sim U(0,1), Y\sim U(y,1), V\sim U(0,1) \\
X , Y , U , V \text{ independent}\\
P(X + U > Y + V)$$
I derived the pdf of $U(x,1) + U(0,1)$ which should be $f(z) = \frac{min(z,1)-max(z-1,x)}{1-x}$ with $z \in (x,2)$

Then integrating with the joint distribution (assuming everything is independent) becomes extremely messy. Is there any other way to derive a closed formula for this?

Comment: It would help to use random variable notation.  e.g. You want to find $P(W+X>Y+Z)$ where $W\sim U(x,1),X\sim U(0,1), Y\sim U(y,1), Z\sim U(0,1)$ are independent., correct?

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: Edited $\perp$s so they're not confused with pairwise independence

Answer (score 1):

Not so messy. For simplicity denote a=1-x and b=1-y. Therefore X=1-a+aX_1, Y=1-b+bY_1 and X_1,Y_1,U,V are independent and uniform on (0,1). Denote R=b-a+U-V. Compute first f(r)=\Pr(aX_1-bY_1>r). Without loss of generality you may assume $a\geq b$. The computation of f(r) is easy if you discuss the position of the corners of the square [0,1]^2 with respect to the line ax-by=r: just an area of triangles or trapezoids (4 cases). Having done this you use the fact that the density of W=U-V is $(1-|w|)_+$ for computing E(f(R))=E(f(b-a+W)) which is given by 4 easy integrals

Comment: Thanks I understood some points of your solution, could you please fix the formulas to make it more clear?

Comment: Writing the formulas is a long business. Which points are obscure to you?

Comment: To summarize and check if I understand correctly, the problem is rephrased as finding $P(b-a+aX_1-bY_1 > V-U)$ where $X_1,Y_1,U,V$ are all uniform in $(0,1)$. Then it's about finding the pdf of $V-U$ and $R=b-a+aX_1-bY_1$ and then the final integral with those two pdfs is still easy to integrate, correct?

Comment: Does the above make sense? @gérard-letac